# How can the tomcat port be cleared?

Tags: tomcat, ports

Once in a day tomcat throws a socket error and I am forced to restart the service. How can the   attached port be cleared without restarting the service

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 0x2749 (A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.): connect()